# Extract sheet date from only specific excel sheet

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-embedded

I wanted to know if it is possible to extract date from only a specific sheet?

I have a folder of several excel file and I want to extract only the sheets between the sheet named "TTP" and the other sheet "TTL". it is not about the position of these sheet but only it these sheets are between these 2 sheet (TTP and TTL as example).

It is possible?

I tried to create a little power query code, but I just found a code who choose only sheet with a special name. But I am looking for the "between these 2 sheet".

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Google Sheets and  Microsoft Excel have different feature sets and will most likely require a different answer each. The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with [excel]"_ and the [excel] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with other spreadsheet software like [google-sheets]."_ Choose one platform and edit tags appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\temp\a.xlsx"), null, true),

start=List.PositionOf(Source[Name],"TTP"),
TabsToKeep=List.Range(Source[Name],start+1,List.PositionOf(Source[Name],"TTL")-start-1),
Filtered= Table.SelectRows(Source, each List.Contains(TabsToKeep, [Name])),

List = List.Union(List.Transform(Filtered[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Filtered, "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

then right click and remove extra columns

**EDIT**
For multiple files, steps spread out for easy follow

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\temp3"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", each List.PositionOf([GetFileData][Item],"TTP")),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.1", each List.PositionOf([GetFileData][Item],"TTL")),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.2", each List.Range([GetFileData][Item],[Custom]+1,[Custom.1]-[Custom]-1)),
#"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Custom.3", each let find = [Custom.2] in Table.SelectRows([GetFileData], each List.Contains(find, [Item]))),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Custom.3", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "GetFileData", "Custom", "Custom.1", "Custom.2"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

Comment: Hello, thanks but your code is only for 1 Excel file. It is possible to adapt your code for a folder of several excel file ? thank !

Comment: see edited answer above for multiple files in folder